# Present perfect or past simple

Tags: present-perfect

> Don't worry, I have written your name on the attendance sheet.

Or

> Don't worry, I wrote your name on the attendance sheet.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the context? What meaning are you trying to convey?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would prefer to use **The Present Perfect tense** because it is linking to the present and has a consequence.

- I **have written** your name on the attendance sheet **so** don't worry.

I can say so because *"We use the Present Perfect to speak about something that happened in the past but is important at the time of speaking"*